# Regex that find words with exactly two 'a'

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'd like a regex that finds word with exactly two `a` (not 3,4,5,.) need pattern? don't have to be in row.
`["taat","weagda","aa"]` is ok,
but not this `["a","eta","aaa","aata","ssdfaasdfa"]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one will work:

```
^[^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]*$
```

More generalized version where you can replace 2 with any number:

```
^(?:[^a]*a){2}[^a]*$
```

The 2 regexes above make use of the fact that `a` is a single character, so we can make sure that all other characters are not `a`. The 2nd one uses repetition notation.

Even more generalized version "not more than n non-overlapping substring" (DOTALL mode enabled):

```
^(?!(?:.*sstr){3})(?:.*sstr){2}.*$
```

Where `sstr` is a regex-escaped substring, and the number of repetition in the negative lookahead must be 1 more than the number we want to match.

This one is slightly trickier, and I use negative look-ahead to make sure the string doesn't contain n + 1 non-overlapping instances of the substring `sstr`, then try to find exactly n non-overlapping instances.

Comment: @Амар Баттулга: Note that my regex is more permissive than yours - check if you want to match something like `'":aa@#$@#%L{`.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation , i think, you can just use string to find out, just use a for loop.

```
mylist = ["taat","weagda","aa","eta","aaa","aata","ssdfaasdfa"];
resultList = [];
for x in mylist:
    count = 0;
    for c in x:
        if c == 'a':
            count = count +1;
    if count == 2:
        resultList.append(x);

print(resultList);
```

Comment: While I agree regex isn't needed here, I think `result_list = [word for word in mylist if word.count('a') == 2]` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with two regexes rather than trying to cram it all into one.

Check that your word matches `a[^a]*a` and does not match `a.*a.*a`

Comment: This doesn't work because `.*` will also match on 'a' characters. Use `[^a]*` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#counter-objects) object for this task.

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: words = ["taat","weagda","aa", "a","eta","aaa","aata","ssdfaasdfa"]

In [3]: [word for word in words if Counter(word)['a'] == 2]
Out[3]: ['taat', 'weagda', 'aa']
```